Sum of independent binomial random variables not following a binomial distribution

Given two independent random variables $X \sim B(n_{X}, p_{X})$ and $Y
\sim B(n_{Y}, p_{Y})$. When $p_{X} \neq p_{Y}$, prove that $X + Y$
does not follow a binomial distribution.

Assume that $X+Y\sim B(n,p)$. I wanna prove $n=n_X +n_Y$. Since then, I'll use two facts: $$\begin{cases} E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)\\ \operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)\end{cases}$$ to come up $$(p_X-p_Y)^2=0$$ which is absurd! But currently, I can't show that $n=n_X +n_Y$. Could someone help me or have another way to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Note that if $p_X=0\not = p_Y$, then $X+Y \sim B(n_Y,p_Y)$ and you do get equality for the expectation and variance even though $(p_X-p_Y)^2>0$.

The problem said to prove $X+Y$ is not binomial, which means you assume $X+Y\sim B(n,p)$ for some $n,p$ and derive a contradiction. There is no requirement to prove $n=n_X+n_Y$, so why you are asking about proving $n=n_X+n_Y$?

Observe that $\Pr(X + Y = n_X + n_Y + 1) = 0$ but $\Pr(X + Y = n_X + n_Y)>0$. This implies that $n = n_X + n_Y$ if $X + Y \sim B(n,p)$ with $p > 0$.

could u explain why $Pr(X+Y=n_X+n_Y)>0$?

As mentioned in the comments, you must assume that $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are non-zero. Then the result follows since $\Pr(X = n_X)$ and $\Pr(Y = n_Y)$ are non-zero.

In order to complement the discussion, here is an alternative approach. We assume that $p_Xp_Y\neq 0$. The generating function of an integer valued random variable $Z$ is defined by $G_Z(s)=\mathbb E\left[s^Z\right]$, $s\in [0,1]$.
The generating function $X$ is $(1-p_X+sp_X)^{n_X}$, that of $Y$ is $(1-p_Y+sp_Y)^{n_Y}$ and by independence,
$$
G_{X+Y}=(1-p_X+sp_X)^{n_X}(1-p_Y+sp_Y)^{n_Y}.
$$
This is a polynomial in $s$, which has roots $1/p_X$ and $1/p_Y$. And the generating function of a binomial distribution has only one root. Having $p_X\neq p_Y$ yields a contradiction.
